# What do the square brackets around parameters mean in the official documentation?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't know how to interpret this notation:

```
timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])
```

**Source:**  https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

I'm using this function with a single keyword argument without inconvenience but I can't understand the reason of this notation ¿Does it have a name? Sorry if this is a duplicate post but I don't know how to google it.

Comment: Much better! Thank you @Andy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This notation is described in the documentation [introduction](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/introduction.html#notation):

> a phrase enclosed in square brackets (`[ ]`) means zero or one occurrences (in other words, the enclosed phrase is optional).

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) you link to also explains the parameters:

> All arguments are optional and default to 0. Arguments may be ints, longs, or floats, and may be positive or negative.

---

The short version: If a parameter is enclosed in square brackets, it is optional.